# Unhandled Exception: CameraException(captureTimeout, Picture capture request timed out)

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera

I had integrated camera plugin into my flutter app. when I call take picture function, I'm getting this error.

[image: Error Message]

Here's my code.

```
d = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
path = "${d.path}/Image_${date.toIso8601String()}.jpeg";
_cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
file = await _cameraController.takePicture();
print("XFile path: ${file.path}");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems, the publishers are working on this issue. 
An alternative for same functionality is this one. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_better_camera

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug caused by camera timeout as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74645). A fix for this issue has been published, updating to the latest version of the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin should solve the issue.